# Returning a set_list is blank

Tags: python

I'm attempting to iterate a list of items and execute a `subprocess.check_output` command using each item in the list. I then use some list comprehension to filter the output and finally `set(list)` to remove duplicates. I'm now trying to return the `set(list)` but it keeps returning `[]`. Could anyone explain what is the problem?

```
def local_file(domain, user_list, debug):
    """function iterates list of target users locally"""
    if debug == True:
        print "Local search based on user-file."
    else:
        pass
    print "Targeted Users Found On LocalHost\n"
    for userl in user_list:
        try:
            out = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/FO", "List", "/FI", "USERNAME eq {0}\{1}" .format(domain, userl)], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            users = [item for item in out.split() if domain in item and userl in item]
            sorted_list = set(users)
            for item in sorted_list:
                print item
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            errormessage = e.output
            print errormessage
    print "\nCompleted"
    return sorted_list
```

Comment: Are you sure that `users` isn't empty?

Comment: please print the users list before it is passed to set( ) function.

Comment: I have already checked that and its not empty.

Comment: the `for item in sorted_list` prints each item successfully too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only `return`ing the last sorted_list set, which must be an empty set at the end of user_list.

It's basically this:

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        var = i
    return var

print f()

>>> 9
```

You should `.append()` your sorted_list to a new list and return that at the end of the function to get everything back:

```
def f():
    varList = []
    for i in range(10):
        var = i
        varList.append(var)
    return varList

print f()
```

Comment: @atlastlogist arr ok that makes sense. would you suggest the following in the for loop? `sorted_list = new_list.append(item)`

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but my first thought would be to make an empty list outside the for loop, then inside the for loop, `new_list.append(sorted_list)` for each set, and `return new_list` at the end.

Comment: it still produces an empty list :$, if i place `return new_list` as you have above. I dont get any `print` items. If i place it in the same place as I have in my original post. I still get blank `return`

Answer (score 0):

As someone else has answered your main problem, overwriting the variable inside the loop, I have rewritten this so it only calls 'tasklist' once and parses the output, instead of calling it over and over for every user in user_list:

```
import subprocess
import csv

user_list = ['Test']
domain='MyPC'

tasklist = subprocess.check_output("tasklist /V /FO CSV")
tasks = csv.DictReader(tasklist.splitlines(), dialect="excel")

users = set()
for task in tasks:
    if task['User Name'] == 'N/A': continue
    task_domain, task_user = task['User Name'].split('\\')

    if domain == task_domain and task_user in user_list:
        users.add(task_user)

print '\n'.join(users)
# return users
```

(Consider [SysInternals' PsLoggedOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx) which queries logged on users quickly via the registry, and can be run against remote computers as well).

Comment: The idea behind the code is to identify accounts being used on systems. So if i had a domain admin account and wanted to know if this is being used incorrectly on my network (ie used as a service account etc etc)

Comment: this doesnt answer the question

Comment: @iNoob someone else had already answered the question, there was nothing else to say there. I have edited my post so it's now a solution which offers _an_ answer to 'listing users with tasklist', although it is a redesign from your original approach.

Comment: i have taken a look at psloggedon, it doesnt contain some functionality that i require, so its not a viable option. thanks anyway ;)

Comment: the `if domain == task_domain and task_user in user_list: users.add(user)` doesnt work as I dont have an "item" in the `if` statement to use to add with?

Comment: @iNoob I notice I put `users.add(user)` but I should have put `users.add(task_user)`. Edited my answer with an update - does that fix it?  If not, then what do you mean about `item` - there is no mention of `item` in my code.